# What type of home security system does not expose cameras to hackers?

Tags: security

All of the home security systems available at Walmart seem to rely on the Internet. Users can check their cameras via the Internet on their phones or work computers.

This seems to introduce a significant security problem, as one has to trust that: (1) employees at the company producing the product are not accessing the cameras; (2) employees to not leak passwords; and (3) there is no security breach at the company enabling anyone to access your camera feeds.

Is there any way to setup a home security system that can similarly notify me of intruders, while I am at work or traveling, but which does not rely on security cameras? Or is there another form of detection which avoids the problem above?

Comment: VTC as off-topic, since it's asking about designing a security system which is not home improvement.

Comment: That said, if you want it to notify you of events while you are away, it necessarily has to connect to the internet or a phone network _somehow_. If it's connected, it's susceptible to hacking, plain and simple, and that applies to pretty much any device, camera or not.

Comment: Door, window, and heat/motion sensors have all been around longer than cameras in home security. Plenty of modern options include connectivity to your smartphone to alert you when they've been triggered.

Answer (score 1):

One that is not connected to an internet service.

Additionally, you can make sure the cameras are behind a good router with a firewall.

Don't shop at Wal Mart, look for a good security camera system that doesn't use an internet service monitor your system.

You should monitor the system unless you want to hire ADT or a similar reputable service.

Good luck!

Comment: If the system does not use Internet, how does it alert me? Is there a method that does not involve paying a monthly subscription, but instead just involves me setting up the equipment?

Comment: Using the internet to alert you is entirely different than using an internet service to monitor the system. If your communications are secure with your home server ther is not a problem.

Comment: @Village. I have an older IP-camera that does not connect to any kind of cloud service but which can communicate using email (like any desktop email program). It doesn't need any kind of separate subscription or service. However these seem harder to find nowadays.